# Create a JavaScript function writing odd numbers between 0 and 15001

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to improve my ability to create efficient algorithms everyday and I am facing an issue with this one... I want to create a JavaScript function loop to write only odd numbers between 0 and 15000:

```
function Nowork() {
       for(x = 1; x < 15001; x+2) {
    document.write(x);
    }
 }

 Nowork();
```

This one doesn't work (also I know document.write should be written only for testing and debugging), instead I know that one works but it only write the even numbers:

```
 function Works() {
       for(x = 1; x < 15001; x++) {
    document.write(x);
   }
 }


 Works();
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do that and also explain to me why my first function doesn't work?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth it means they dont know to assign `x+2` back to `x`

Comment: use `x+=2` instead of `x+2`

Comment: Doesn't works mean it write anything in the browser on jsfidlle

Comment: function Nowork() {
       for(x = 1; x < 15001; x+=2) {
    document.write(x);
    }
 }

 Nowork(); also works thanks guys !!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this:

```
function Nowork() {
    for(x = 1; x < 15001; x=x+2) {
        document.write(x);
    }
}

Nowork();
```

you cant use +2 like that.

Comment: it works !!! Thank you very much..excuse me I am a newbie

Comment: And do you know why I can't use it like that? Because it almost look the same...

Comment: You can't use it like that because x++ is short for x=x+1 but there is no short method for adding 2 or more.